# AutoMapper 5.X throw exception when map IDataReader while on 3.X version is OK

Tags: c#, automapper

```
{
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(connectionString, commandText, parms))
    {
        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            var list  = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<T>>(reader);
            return list.ToList();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This code works fine on AutoMapper 3.3.1, but when I upgrade to the latest 5.1.1 version,  It throw the exception :

Error mapping types.
Mapping types:
IDataReader -> List`1
System.Data.IDataReader -> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[....]

Configuration:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                //MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new DataReaderMapper { YieldReturnEnabled = true }); 4.x.x
                //cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
                cfg.AddProfile<MapperProfile>();
            });
        }
    }

    public class MapperProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<System.Data.IDataReader, TestModel>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've not included much information, such as how you are configuring and initialising AutoMapper, nor the full error message.  It's pretty hard to guess at what's wrong without that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDataReader is not supported today in 5.0. I took it out because I didn't write it nor do I use it. It's in a separate repository, github.com/automapper/automapper.data, waiting for someone who actually *does* use it to port it.

Maybe you would like to pitch in?